# HL7 Error: MSA|AE|0000000|Field [AccessionNo] is required;

Tags: hl7

I'm using HL7Soup as my HL7 Client to add a new patient record to no avail. Can anyone help me fix an error I received? I have checked HL7 manual on the net, it didn't help as it is very unreliable.

I sent the following message using the client:

```
MSH|^~\&|HL7Soup|Instance1|HL7Soup|Instance2|20160928142250|1|ADT^A28|0000000|D|2.5.1|1|2|||||||2
EVN|NW|20160928154802|20160928154805|O|1|20160928154821|1
PID|1984|1984|1984|1-1984|Rey Allan|||||||||||||12345x|||||||5||||||||||||||
PV1|1984|R|||||||||||||||||0||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||00001|ACSN||
```

And got the following response:

```
MSH|^~\&|HL7Soup|Instance2|HL7Soup|Instance1|20160928163118|1|ORR^O02|0000000|D|2.5.1|1|2
    MSA|AE|0000000|Field [AccessionNo] is required;
```

I don't know which field it's trying to refer to. I checked the manual it suggests 'Visit Number', I changed it, but still had the error. Help Pls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I think you try to send an ADT message to a system that is configured to receive order (ORM) messages. 
The answer you get is an ORR^O02 (a reply to an order message).
The answer requests an accession number. Those are typically used in order entry not in ADT.

You did provide a visit number (PV1-19): 0

Maybe you use the wrong system or the wrong port?

To connect to a remote system I would recommend that you use a library like HAPI (http://hl7api.sourceforge.net) or something like Apache Camel (http://camel.apache.org/hl7) or Mirth Connect. There are many pitfalls in MLLP (the protocol usually used).

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll look into it.

Comment: I sent the following message and got the response below, I checked the RIS system. the patient on the ORM messsage didn't appear. What could be the problem?

Comment: **HL7 Message (ORM)**

  `MSH|^~\&|HL7Soup|Instance1|HL7Soup|Instance2|20060307110114||ORM^A28|MSGID20060307110114|P|2.5.1
PID||15000001|12001||Test^Test^^^Mr.||19670824|M|||123 West St.^^Denver^CO^80020^USA|||||||
PV1||O|OP^PAREG^||||2342^Test^Test|||MED|||||||||2|||||||||||||||||||||||||20160929110111|
ORC|NW|20160929110111|00575||SC||20081225150000+000|||15000001^Test||BCBS|1FLR203RM|312-555-1234|||AGH|
OBR|1|20160929110111||003038^Urinalysis^L|||20160929110111`

Comment: **Response**
`MSH|^~\&|HL7Soup|Instance2|HL7Soup|Instance1|20160929153703||ORR^O02|MSGID20060307110114|P|2.5.1
MSA|AA|MSGID20060307110114`


Message Acknowledgment (MSA)
(MSGID20060307110114) Coded as original mode: application accept - enhanced mode: application acknowledgment: accept

Thanks in advance again

Comment: You should look into the documentation of the receiving system. It should state exactly what to send and ideally provide samples. This is becoming a reverse engineering project. You should seriously consider getting some training in HL7 or read the specs (very tedious). You try to send ORM^A28. This event type plainly does not exist. The approach is legit, however. Sending ADT in ORM^O01 does work, sometimes (if the vendor plays nice). Go ask your RIS vendor.

Comment: I'd tried sending the ORM^001 message and  finally created record to the RIS system, but when I tried sending from my custom application I created which the code is in the link below, I'm not receiving any response from HL7 Server. What could be the problem in my code or in the message I was sending.

http://pastebin.com/b2J3z3J9

Comment: I added a few links to tools/libs you could use to connect. You can do it yourself. However I would advise against it.